# List all own cmdlets

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-cmdlet

Is it possible to list all own cmdlets in PowerShell 4.0?

What do I have to add to a cmdlet to get this functionality? For instance, does `mycmdlet:...` instead of `global:...` help?

Answer (score 0):

To list all currently loaded CmdLets use the following:

```
Get-Module | ForEach-Object -Process { Get-Command -Module $_.Name }
```

Note that the above will only show loaded modules. The more modules that are loaded in memory, the more CmdLets you will see. To discover additional modules that you may import, run a command like the following:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable
```

And if you are feeling *realy* lucky, run this to get it all, be prepared to sit back and watch, because this command could take a while:

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable | ForEach-Object -Process { Import-Module -Name $_.Name -Force ; Get-Command -Module $_.Name -OutVariable $AllTheCommandsICanSee }
```